# new angular 8 application return http 400

Tags: node.js, angular

I am facing a strange error. I am creating new clean angular 8 app and successfully built code but try to open application at localhost:4200 (or any port I changed to) app return **http 400**

I have added build info. Uninstall node js and re-install it and still same

```
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 49.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 264 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 10.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.08 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-10-21T10:00:41.976Z - Hash: 8acb354556900c2f8710 - Time: 9192ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Well that is strange. What about restarting `ng serve` and also Ctrl + F5 in the browser?

Comment: tried them. still same. also restarted PC

Comment: 400 or 404 ? what happens when you `ng serve --o`

Comment: 400
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: have you tried verifying npm cache ? `npm cache verify`

Comment: yes i have tried verify command also clean and veriyf. same result

Comment: is there any log files for nodejs ?

Comment: Add the image for which you are getting 400 like chrome developer tools network tab one and console log one

Comment: well i updated nodejs to 12 and now got **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 43**

Comment: when i try to connect using ip adress i can access the angular application but not using localhost
**ng serve --host 0.0.0.0**

Answer (score -2):

May be there is something in your server.js file in nodejs app. Are you allowing requests from all urls ? You need to enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

Comment: did not change any setting all of them are at default settings and  how to check CORS ?

Comment: This should be added as a comment not the Answer.

Comment: you need to set that using cros pkg in that server file @S.AzizKazdal